# Moving marker GMap.Net

Tags: vb.net, gmap.net

MarkerA: Lat 21.192 , Lng 40.453
MarkerB: Lat 24.822 , Lng 46.718
MarkerC it's custom marker as a plane: Lat 21.192 , Lng 40.453

Using **VB.NET** AND **GMap.NET**, how can I make MarkerC moves toward MarkerB smoothly?

I need your help please to do that I'm done with Form load and can see all the markers on the Map, just need the animation step.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GMap.NET, but what you could do is calculate the parametric equation of the line from A to B, then use a timer to calculate the position of C. (If you only find 3D examples for creating a parametric equation of a line between two points then just ignore the third dimension part.) As long as the line doesn't go over 0° and you don't want the path along a great circle, it will probably be good enough.

Comment: Any command or help please ??